# How to get total sum of each month?

Tags: sql

I've tried to get net total sum of total. This is the query that i've wrote. I don't know how to get the total sum.

```
SELECT 
MONTHNAME(mohon_tarikh) as mname, 
count(pemohon_id) as total
FROM tpermohonan
WHERE year(mohon_tarikh) = '2019'
GROUP BY MONTH(mohon_tarikh)
```

The result from the query:

```
mname      total
January    3478
February   753
March      840
April      658
May        2388
June       848
July       739
August     621
September  2110
October    1625
November   697
December   964
```

Comment: GROUP BY MONTHNAME(mohon_tarikh) instead of GROUP BY MONTH(mohon_tarikh) ?

Comment: Total sum of what? How does this result you're getting differ from what you're expecting? A lot of information is missing in your question for us to help you. I'd recommend reading [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some pointers on what a question should include, as well as creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query).

Comment: Oh sorry. What i meant was I want to find total sum  if we summed all months together. Do u get what i mean? Sorry, i'm not really good in Eng. Ex: jan + feb + march + apr + may + june + july + august + sep + oct + nov + dis = total

Comment: a query like "SELECT count(pemohon_id) as total FROM tpermohonan WHERE year(mohon_tarikh) = '2019';" should work.

Comment: yeah it works! thanks a lot! but how do i combine the query i wrote and urs ? i want to fetch all the data for each month and the total sum.

Comment: like in excel, do you want the total at the bottom?

Comment: yeah, that what i want.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for window functions. You did not mention database, but just to give you example see [Postgresql window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/tutorial-window.html)

Answer (score 0):

a query using union all will get the result you need -

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(mohon_tarikh) AS mname,
       count(pemohon_id) AS total
FROM tpermohonan
WHERE year(mohon_tarikh) = '2019'
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(mohon_tarikh)

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Total',
       count(pemohon_id) AS total
FROM tpermohonan
WHERE year(mohon_tarikh) = '2019'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `with rollup`.  I would suggest:

```
SELECT MAX(MONTHNAME(mohon_tarikh)) as mname, count(pemohon_id) as total
FROM tpermohonan
WHERE mohon_tarikh >= '2019-01-01' AND
      mohon_tarikh < '2020-01-01'
GROUP BY MONTH(mohon_tarikh) WITH ROLLUP;
```

Notes:

- The `GROUP BY` columns and unaggregated columns in the `SELECT` should match.  For that reason, I put `MAX()` around the `MONTHNAME()`.
- The date comparisons are often more efficient if they are direct date comparisons rather than using functions on columns.
- The `WITH ROLLUP` does what you want.
- Aggregating by `MONTH()` should return the rows in chronological order rather than alphabetically by month name.

Comment: hey, thanks a lot! it does work the way i wanted but here's a little problem. the total value renamed as month name? How do i fix that? For example, it supposed to come out like this :  mname      total
January    3478
February   753
March      840
April      658
May        2388
June       848
July       739
August     621
September  2110
October    1625
November   697
December   964, Total  15721

Comment: , however it came out like this: mname      total
January    3478
February   753
March      840
April      658
May        2388
June       848
July       739
August     621
September  2110
October    1625
November   697
December   964, September  15721.

Comment: If you want the result set in a particular order, you can use `order by`.  Is that the issue?  You never specified the database, so it is hard to be more specific.

Comment: Table: tpermohonan

mohon_id | pemohon_id  | mohon_tarikh | mohon_tarikhluput | mohon_online | 

       1        |            2         |  2019-12-23    |  2020-12-23            |              1         |
       4        |            11       |  2019-07-17    |  2020-07-17            |              0         |

this is the example of my database. sorry, i couldn't attach the picture.

Comment: i just wanted to generate monthly report based as below :

mname      total
January    3478
February   753
March      840
April      658
May        2388
June       848
July       739
August     621
September  2110
October    1625
November   697
December   964
Total            15721

I did as u've told me and it work but the output is quite weird and idk how to fix this.

Comment: The output i get :


mname
total
January
3478
February
753
March
840
April
658
May
2388
June
848
July
739
August
621
September
2110
October
1625
November
697
December
964
September
15721

My question is: why the total became september?