# Multiple JOINS using UNION ALL with WHERE clause

Tags: php, sql, join

I wanted to generate a report. User have to select position name using dropdown menu. This the the query that I've wrote but it's not working and I  don't how else need to fix. Any helps appreciated.

```
SELECT * FROM 
                (
                    SELECT COUNT(tapplied.applied_id) as TotalCandidate, exam_code.exam_name 
                    FROM ((exam 
                    INNER JOIN tapplied ON exam.applied_id = tapplied.applied_id) 
                    INNER JOIN exam_code ON exam.exam_id = exam_code.exam_id) 
                    WHERE exam_code.exam_id <> '8' 
                    GROUP BY exam_name 

                    UNION ALL 
                 
                    SELECT COUNT(tapplied.exam_id) as TotalCandidate, level_code.level_name
                    FROM ((tipt INNER JOIN tapplied ON tipt.applied_id = tapplied.applied_id)
                    INNER JOIN level_code ON tipt.level_id = level_code.level_id)
                    GROUP BY level_name
                ) x
                WHERE x.position_name = '{$jaw}'
```

Comment: Where is the code that you tried?

Comment: If you don't have a foreign key, how is the data related? Show some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: Do you have another table that contains the relationship?

Comment: When you tried that query, did you get the desired result?

Comment: When you use `UNION`, both subqueries have to return the same number of columns.

Comment: You need to show more than 1 row of sample data in each table, so I can see how they relate to the desired output. And you have to show the desired output.

Comment: Joins are not on keys, they are on conditions. Constraints are not needed to query. PS [mre] [ask] [help] PS Clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: Do not totally change a post to ask a new question. Edit per feedback. If you have a different question then post a new question post. Do not edit in a way that invalidates a posted answer. You just changed this post a lot--different columns, multiple inner joins instead of cross joins. However this version is more or less similar in structure to the version before your recent changes & there are no answer posts so I did not roll back to the last version in the original form. Both this post & the original form need a [mre]. [ask] [Help]

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. [ask] [Help]

Comment: I now see that this rewrite is the 5th version of essentially the same question you have asked in 4 posts. Please do not repost questions. Edit per feedback including giving a [mre]. https://stackoverflow.com/q/67428652/3404097 https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/67613769/7 https://stackoverflow.com/q/68077072/3404097 https://stackoverflow.com/q/70196001/3404097 PS Poorly received posts count towards limits on posting new question, whether deleted or not. Also poorly reasking a poorly asked question just gets more downvotes. Edit per feedback.