# Generate report using dropdown menu

Tags: php, mysql

I want to generate report based on year by using dropdown menu. User can choose any year using dropdown menu and the report will be display according the year chosen. The problem is, the report does not generate at all.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
include('_header.php');

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ea");
$sql = "SELECT distinct YEAR(mohon_tarikh)
     AS  tahun
FROM tpermohonan
order by tahun";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

?>
        
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center" valign="top">
    <td bordercolor="#0c52cb"><p>&nbsp;</p>
                
        <table bgcolor="#2F72B9" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" align="center" width="72%" >
            <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" >
            
                <form class ="" action ="" name="menufrmLaporanStatTransak"  method="post" target= "_blank">
                    <td width="12%">Pilih Tahun<font class="font18red">*</font>: </td>
                    <td width="9%"><select class = "" name = "y">
                        <?php while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                        echo '<option value = "'.$rows["tahun"].'">'.$rows["tahun"].'</option>';
                        }?></select></td>
                </form>
                
                    <td width="8%"><button type= "submit" name= "button" > Cari</button></td>
                    <td width="8%"><p align="right"><a href = "#" onclick = "window.print();"><img src="img/cetak.png" alt="cetak" width="40" height="40"><br>
                    </a><a href = "#" onclick = "window.print();">Cetak</a></td>
                    <td width="34%" align="right"><?php date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur"); echo "Tarikh : " .date('d-m-Y H:i:s'); //Returns IST ?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

```
  <tr>
    <td width="33" rowspan="3"><div align="center"><strong>BIL</strong></div></td>
    <td width="550" rowspan="3"><div align="center"><strong>JAWATAN</strong></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="12"><div align="center"><strong>BILANGAN TRANSAKSI </strong></div></td>
    <td width="136" rowspan="2"><div align="center"><strong>JUMLAH</strong></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="82"><div align="center"><strong>JANUARI</strong></div></td>
    <td width="88"><div align="center"><strong>FEBRUARI</strong></div></td>
    <td width="50"><div align="center"><strong>MAC</strong></div></td>
    <td width="60"><div align="center"><strong>APRIL</strong></div></td>
    <td width="51"><div align="center"><strong>MEI</strong></div></td>
    <td width="41"><div align="center"><strong>JUN</strong></div></td>
    <td width="57"><div align="center"><strong>JULAI</strong></div></td>
    <td width="60"><div align="center"><strong>OGOS</strong></div></td>
    <td width="119"><div align="center"><strong>SEPTEMBER</strong></div></td>
    <td width="100"><div align="center"><strong>OCTOBER</strong></div></td>
    <td width="117"><div align="center"><strong>NOVEMBER</strong></div></td>
    <td width="106"><div align="center"><strong>DISEMBER</strong></div></td>    
 </tr>
    
    
<?php 
    **if(isset($_POST['y']))**
    **{**   
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ea");
        **$thn = $_POST['y'];**
        $sql = ("SELECT 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.jawatan_nama) Bil,
          t.jawatan_nama Jawatan,
          COUNT(IF(month_id = 1, 1, NULL)) Jan,
          COUNT(IF(month_id = 2, 1, NULL)) Feb,
          COUNT(IF(month_id = 3, 1, NULL)) March,
          COUNT(IF(month_id = 4, 1, NULL)) April,
          COUNT(IF(month_id = 5, 1, NULL)) May,
          COUNT(IF(month_id = 6, 1, NULL)) June,
          COUNT(IF(month_id = 7, 1, NULL)) July,

          COUNT(IF(month_id = 8, 1, NULL)) August,
          COUNT(IF(month_id = 9, 1, NULL)) Sep,
          COUNT(IF(month_id = 10, 1, NULL)) Oct,
          COUNT(IF(month_id = 11, 1, NULL)) Nov,
          COUNT(IF(month_id = 12, 1, NULL)) Dis,
          COUNT(*) Total
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
        t1.jawatan_nama,
        MONTH(t3.mohon_tarikh) month_id
        FROM kod_jawatan t1 
            INNER JOIN tmohonjaw t2 ON t1.jawatan_id = t2.jawatan_id
            INNER JOIN tpermohonan t3 ON t3.mohon_id = t2.mohon_id
        **WHERE t3.mohon_tarikh = '{$thn}'**
    ) t
    GROUP BY t.jawatan_nama");
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    echo "$count rekod dijumpai<br/>";
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    
        ?>

            <tr>
              <td width="33"><div align="center"><?php echo $row['Bil']?></td>
                <td width="550"><?php echo $row['Jawatan']?></td>
                <td width="82"><div align="center"><?php echo $row['Jan']?></div></td>
                <td width="88"><div align="center"><?php echo $row['Feb']?></div></td>
                <td width="50"><div align="center"><?php echo $row['March']?></div></td>
                <td width="60"><div align="center"><?php echo $row['April']?></div></td>
                <td width="51"><div align="center"><?php echo $row['May']?></div></td>
                <td width="41"><div align="center"><?php echo $row['June']?></div></td>
                <td width="57"><div align="center"><?php echo $row['July']?></div></td>
                <td width="60"><div align="center"><?php echo $row['August']?></div></td>
                <td width="119"><div align="center"><?php echo $row['Sep']?></div></td>
                <td width="100"><div align="center"><?php echo $row['Oct']?></div></td>
                <td width="117"><div align="center"><?php echo $row['Nov']?></div></td>
                <td width="106"><div align="center"><?php echo $row['Dis']?></div></td>
                <td width="136"><div align="center"><?php echo $row['Total']?></div></td>
            </tr>
            
      
        <?php }
**}**
    ?>
```

The output is like this before i've added which I marks with ** code **:
This is the ouput of all years:

[image]

After I'v added ** code **, the output became like this:
[image]

I don't know where it went wrong. Could somebody help me please?

Comment: [mre] Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Answer (score 0):

try this if working
you need to put the button inside of form

```
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" >
        
            <form class ="" action ="" name="menufrmLaporanStatTransak"  method="post" target= "_blank">
                <td width="12%">Pilih Tahun<font class="font18red">*</font>: </td>
                <td width="9%"><select class = "" name = "y">
                    <?php while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                    echo '<option value = "'.$rows["tahun"].'">'.$rows["tahun"].'</option>';
                    }?></select></td>
                <td width="8%"><button type= "submit" name= "button" > Cari</button></td>
            </form>
            
                
                <td width="8%"><p align="right"><a href = "#" onclick = "window.print();"><img src="img/cetak.png" alt="cetak" width="40" height="40"><br>
                </a><a href = "#" onclick = "window.print();">Cetak</a></td>
                <td width="34%" align="right"><?php date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur"); echo "Tarikh : " .date('d-m-Y H:i:s'); //Returns IST ?></td>
        </tr>
```

then change the isset

```
  if(isset($_POST['button']))
{   
//your code here
}
```

or you can use this in select

```
<select class = "" name = "y" onchange="this.form.submit()">
```

hope this could help